# Fix/find outlet with round dimmer switch

Tags: dimmer-switch

[See photos]

[image]

[image]

I have an outlet on the wall of the stairs that has two switches (different sets of lights).  The left switch was a round dimmer type switch. Push on/off and rotate to dim (infrequently used).

I snagged it with a package and broke the little round knob off (broke the metal pin, not just the knob coming off).

Would like to replace/fix it.  Went to the local big box, but they did not have that sort of outlet or switch.  And I hate those little slider dimmer things next to switches (always end up dimming when you don't want to).

Is there somewhere I can order a replacement part? (either pin or entire outlet)?  Like on the Internet?  [I have never done this...so sorry the stupid question...I just cried when Home Depot failed me.]  Failing that, could I just make it two regular switches (no dimming)?  I hate, hate the little slider things next to switch that always dim when you didn't mean to touch them.

Note: I am very home improvement, tools, and electricity stupid.  Can follow directions though if I buy something and have put in new lights and stuff (with difficulty)

EDIT: After action.  TLDR: replaced with a new switch, fine.
Details:  Thanks for the answer and comments.  Tried the JB Weld (had to buy some), but no joy...it's got too much tangential forces on it and also, hard to clamp/hold the pieces to set properly.  Rewiring was fine.  I could have used a single pole, but the enclosed directions were clear on how to use it for single pole application.  Thanks for the comments on pictures and breakers.  Really easier than I expected!

Comment: You could try a product like J-B weld and reattach it. If it does or doesn't work it would be a cheap try at repairing it.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Wiring-Devices-Light-Controls-Dimmers/Rotary/N-5yc1vZc34iZ1z17kz0

Comment: When you go to change the dimmer, take many pictures before you disconnect existing wires. Don't forget to turn off the breaker(s) for everything in the box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment-answers.  Will get the project done and then accept an answer.  I hate non-Googlers, but was intimidated to specify what I was looking for...and of course the idio...I mean associate at Home Despot had told me "they don't make that anymore...".  Love to just replace/fix the mechanical part.  But will do the wiring if needed.  Little worried that the 50 year later replacement (Even though looks same) may have different wires/connection points...had that happen with other things.  TTYL and thanks for the newbie kindness.

Comment: This looks like two switches to me, not an outlet.

Comment: Yeah...I realized an outlet and a switch are different things after starting to Google.  Not so good at the terminology.  Will know from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to find on Amazon under “round dimmer switch”. You need to know if the switch you are replacing is “single pole” or “3-way”. Single pole means only this switch controls the light. 3-way means this switch and another switch both control the light.

This particular switch will work either way (but not all are like this):
[https://www.amazon.com/GE-Rotating-Dimmable-Incandescent-18020/dp/B002DNG3EE/ref=psdc_6291358011_t2_B002DN2PGY?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002DNG3EE)

Comment: Just make sure whatever you get is UL or ETL listed. That GE is UL listed. But a **lot** of Amazon stuff is drop-ship from across the Pacific with little regard to electrical safety.